# How to delete duplicate record and keep the most recent recording?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
Country_city('id', 'country_id', 'City_id')
```

and duplicate records on it that I select with:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id), 
    COUNT(CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id)) 
FROM Country_City
GROUP BY CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id) 
HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id)) > 1
```

and the result looks like:

```
CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id)  |  COUNT(CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id))
MA07+11                           |  48
MA07+13                           |  5
...
```

and i tried to delete them i execute this:

```
DELETE FROM Country_City 
WHERE id NOT IN (
           SELECT MAX(id) 
           FROM Country_City 
           GROUP BY CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id)
           );
```

It's not working; is there any problem with my request ? How to delete duplicated data and keep one record ?

Comment: Have you tried putting an alias in your `SELECT MAX(id) as id`?

Comment: [Find and remove duplicates](http://buysql.com/mysql/30-find-and-remove-duplicates.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using your `CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id)`:

```
DELETE cc FROM Country_City cc
INNER JOIN
(
               SELECT CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id) as cKey,MAX(id) as id 
               FROM Country_City 
               GROUP BY CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id)
               HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(Country_id, '+', City_id)) > 1           
) ccs on CONCAT(cc.Country_id, '+', cc.City_id) = ccs.cKey 
             and ccs.id != cc.id;
```

Though `CONCAT` is probably not necessary here so you can also use:

```
DELETE cc FROM Country_City cc
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT Country_id,City_id,MAX(id) as id 
 FROM Country_City 
 GROUP BY Country_id,City_id
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1           
) ccs on cc.Country_id = ccs.Country_id 
      and cc.City_id = ccs.City_id 
      and ccs.id != cc.id;
```